# for_each throws an error after it has been "moved"

Tags: terraform

So, i have used a for_each in each resource earlier.
And now I have moved that to the module.

```
module "architect" {  
  source = "./modules/architect"
  for_each = toset(var.vm_names)
  vm_name = each.value
  vm_key = each.key
}
```

I have also defined up the vm_name and vm_key in /modules/architect/variables.tf:

```
variable "vm_name" {
  type = string
}

variable "vm_key" {
  type = string
}
```

I`m trying to set a public IP address on each VM.
And this worked fine when I had the for_each(commented out) in each resource.

```
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "pubip" {
    #for_each = toset(var.vm_names)
  name                = "${var.vm_name}-PublicIp"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rsg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rsg.location
  allocation_method   = "Dynamic"

}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "main" {
    #for_each = toset(var.vm_names)
  name                = "${var.vm_name}-nic"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rsg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rsg.name


  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "testconfiguration1"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.subnet.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    public_ip_address_id          = azurerm_public_ip.pubip[var.vm_key].id
  }
```

The error it throws here is:

```
Error: Invalid index

  on modules\architect\main.tf line 109, in resource "azurerm_network_interface" "main":
 109:     public_ip_address_id          = azurerm_public_ip.pubip[var.vm_key].id
    |----------------
    | azurerm_public_ip.pubip is object with 16 attributes
    | var.vm_key is "OSL-SPLK-HF01"

The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

Here is the block for the 109 line, where the last line is the number 109:

```
  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "testconfiguration1"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.subnet.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    public_ip_address_id          = azurerm_public_ip.pubip[var.vm_key].id
```

What is the reason I get this error?

I have used each.key there before.

Comment: What is the structure of `var.vm_names`? Do you have any example to show?

Comment: Sorry, forgot that.

   `variable "vm_names" {
    type = list(string)
    default = [
      "OSL-SPLK-SH01",
      "OSL-SPLK-CM", 
      "OSL-SPLK-IDX01", 
      "OSL-SPLK-IDX02", 
      "OSL-SPLK-DS", 
      "OSL-SPLK-HF01"]
}`

Comment: I see. So you are passing `var.vm_names` into the module. What about `var.vm_key`? `var.vm_names` is definitely not `var.vm_key`, thus you get errors.

Comment: But i`m passing var.vm_key also?
like, i have this: 
vm_key = each.key

And, then have assign it to the variable file?

Comment: They way you have it now, your ` vm_key` in the module, will be just values from `vm_names`. In your code without modules, they are clearly different variables.

Comment: So, what is the way to continue here so i also can get the key?
This worked fine when I had the for_each just in the resource module, and could just set each.value and each.key

Comment: In your context, `each.value == each.key` - there is no difference between them.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a `resource` block without `for_each` set at all, referring to it in other expressions returns just a single object rather than a map of objects.

For that reason, once you factor out the `for_each` into the calling module block rather than each individual resource it's no longer correct to try to access individual instances of your resources, as you did in the expression `azurerm_public_ip.pubip[var.vm_key].id`. Instead, you should just refer directly to the single object that resource now represents:

```
   public_ip_address_id          = azurerm_public_ip.pubip.id
```

Notice that within the namespace of each particular module instance there is only one `azurerm_public_ip.pubip`, so you can just refer directly to it. Because the `for_each` is now on the module call itself rather than on the individual resources, Terraform will assign these resources addresses shaped like this:

```
module.architect["OSL-SPLK-HF01"].azurerm_public_ip.pubip
```

...whereas when you had the resources in the root with their own `for_each` arguments, Terraform would address them like this:

```
module.architect.azurerm_public_ip.pubip["OSL-SPLK-HF01"]
```

The index now exists in the *calling* module rather than in the *called* module, so the architect module itself has no awareness that it's being used with `for_each`, but any references to the outputs of that module in the caller will need to include a key like you were previously doing with the resource instances:

```
# the "foo" output value associated with the "OSL-SPLK-HF01"
# instance of the module.
module.architect["OSL-SPLK-HF01"].foo
```